# Error Atomation runbook in Azure portal

Tags: azure, automation, portal

When I go to my run book on the azure [portal](https://portal.azure.com) and I try to modify it, i got this error:

> ERROR Unable to locate blade '##NOT_SPECIFIED##' in extension definition. Search path:'[0]Microsoft_Azure_Automation-[1]##NOT_SPECIFIED##'.

Comment: This looks like a bug in portal (see similar error here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/issues/429). I would recommend reaching out to Azure Support. They should be able to help you with this.

Comment: Thanks [tag:gaurav-mantri]

Comment: The error can be bypass by using the azure management portal at http://manage.windowsazure.com

Comment: Please put this as an answer.

Comment: this not an not a resolution, this is a bypass

Comment: Please answer the following questions to help the Azure Automation team debug.  How was this runbook created?  Can you go from Browse>Automation Account > Select your runbook to view the runbook blade?  Do you have any other resources in your Automation account which are not loading?